# Select data from mysql with PHP and Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I want to fetch all the records by filtering a role from a dropdown list. This was working perfectly.

(1) But I want to display all the records by default, only when I select the role, all the role users should be filtered.

(2) I want to make my code shorten instead of writing the code two pages, could we fetch all the data from members.php, instead of using memlist.php again.

members.php

```
 <html>    
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqueryv1.10.2.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
         function showUser(str)
         { 
           document.getElementById("getrole").style.display="block";
           if (str =="")
           {
              document.getElementById("getrole").innerHTML="";
              return;
           } 
           if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
           else { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
           xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
           {
             if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { document.getElementById("getrole").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; }
           }
           xmlhttp.open("GET","memlist.php?role="+str,true);
           xmlhttp.send();
         }
        </script>
    </head>    
    <body>     
           <?php
               echo 'Select the role : <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">';
                     $sel_role = $db->query('SELECT * FROM role');
                     $sel_role->execute();
                     echo '<option selected="selected">Select a role</option>';
                     while ($row = $sel_role->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
                     {
                       $role_id = $row['role_id'];
                       $role_name = $row['role_name'];  
                       echo '<option value='.$role_id.'>'.$role_name.'</option>';         
                     }
               echo '</select>';              
               echo '<div id="getrole"></div><input type="hidden" value='.$role_id.'>';          
            ?>       
   </body>
</html>
```

memlist.php

```
<?php
    require 'init.php';

    $uid = $_GET['role'];

    $dis_role = $db->prepare('SELECT bu.*, br.* FROM users bu JOIN role br ON bu.role_id = br.role_id WHERE br.id = '.$uid.'');
    $dis_role->execute();

    echo '<table id="result">
           <tr><th><label>USERNAME</label></th>                                   
               <th><label>ROLE</label></th>            
           </tr>';    
    foreach($dis_role as $dr)   
    {
            echo '<tr>
                   <td>'.$dr['username'].'</td>                                     
                   <td>'.$dr['role_name'].'</td>                        
                  </tr>';                           
    }   
    echo '</table>';    
?>
```

Comment: Use ajax table for role based filter option. **[Refer this link](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)**. Also for shortening your code use **[jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** instead of pure ajax

Comment: Thank You Ranjith.. The link you have sent was static kind.. could you suggest me dynamic (like working with queries) as my example above.

Comment: Yes. You can send `JSON` resulted value from the server. And populate with data tables. **[This is an simple, how the AJAX will work in dataTables](http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html)** Did you aware of jQuery ajax?